# Exclusão ajax + jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Qual método correto para conseguir deletar, a minha duvida está sendo como pega o id baseado na linha da tabela, e como enviar o mesmo para uma pagina que exclui de fato. Os códigos que já tenho feito estará á seguir.

listaUsuario.php

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("#elemento-pai-da-tabela").on('click', '.btn_Excluir', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var $trPai = $(this).parent().parent(); 
        var id = $trPai.data('id'); 
        $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
            data: { 'COD_IDENT_USUAR': id }, 
            url: "excluirUsuario.php", 
            success: function(msg) { 
                $trPai.remove(); 
            } 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
<?php

    // incluindo o arquivo que faz a conexao com o banco
    include ("../includes/conexao.php");

    // Listando os Cargos

    // executa  query de consulta e armazena o resultado devolvido na variável $resultado
     $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT TXT_NOMEX_USUAR, TXT_ENDER_EMAIL, FLG_STATU_USUAR, DAT_ULTIM_LOGIN, COD_IDENT_USUAR from tbl_USUARIOS");


    // se não existir cargos cadastrados exibe uma mensagem
    if(mysql_num_rows($resultado)<=0)
    {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-error'>";
        echo "<b>Atenção!</b><br>";
        echo "Não existe cargo cadastrado no momento.";
        echo "</div>";
    }

    // se existir produtos cadastrados lista-os
    else
    {
        echo "<table class='table table-striped'>";
        echo "<th class='excluir'>Excluir</th>";
        echo "<th class='alterar'>Alterar</th>";
        echo "<th>Nome</th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<th>Status</th>";
        echo "<th>Último Login</th>";

        while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
        {
            echo "<tr data-id='$linha[4]'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><a href='excluirUsuario.php' class='btn_Excluir'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i></a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='excluirUsuario.php' class='btn_Alterar'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i></a></td>";
            echo "<td>$linha[0]</td>";
            echo "<td>$linha[1]</td>";
            echo "<td>$linha[2]</td>";
            echo "<td>$linha[3]</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

excluiUsuario.php

```
<?php
     // incluindo o arquivo que faz a conexao com o banco
    include ("../includes/conexao.php");

    // Recebendo o valor enviado pelo link
    $COD_IDENT_USUAR = isset($_POST['COD_IDENT_USUAR']) ? $_POST['COD_IDENT_USUAR'] : '';

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl_Usuarios WHERE COD_IDENT_USUAR ='".$COD_IDENT_USUAR."'");

    //fechando a conexao com o banco
    mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Utilizando estes códigos, não estou conseguinte efetuar o delete, ele envia a pagina excluirUsuario.php porem nada acontece.

Comment: Você não criou uma pergunta dessa ontem ?

Comment: Não, este é um novo erro, porque meu outro post foi desativado.

Comment: Transforme o `btn_Excluir` em id e coloque o script no final da pagina, se quiser colocar no começo use a função ready do JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(o botão de alterar aponta pra mesma página que o botão de apagar, eu acho que não é isso que você quer!)

Você está criando *duas*, não *uma* linha na tabela:

```
echo "<tr data-id='$linha[4]'>";
echo "<tr>";
```

O `$trPai` faz referência ao segundo `<tr>`, que não tem o `data-id`; se você tirar essa linha o problema deve se resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se o id que está na tr, está sendo enviado mesmo pelo ajax, se não estiver sendo enviado tente mudar seu javascript. Se você se tem o .btn_Excluir dentro da tr, use ele como seletor e para pegar o id da tr através .closest().

```
$(function(){
    $(".btn_Excluir").on("click", function(){
        var id = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-id");
        if(id != null){
           //Ajax aqui
        } 
    });
});
```